# how to integrate code behind variables to the linkbutton in the design view

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, code-behind

I just need to use the count value which will be generated on the code behind page on the designer view :

```
public void BindCount()
{
    int count = caravans.GetNoOfCaravansGreater2000();
}
```

Designer View :

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPrice3" runat="server" CommandArgument="2000+" OnClick="lnkPrice3_Click">Greater than 2000(<%=count %>)</asp:LinkButton>
```

I tried the above syntax but it doesnt works, Any advice or suggestions will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `Text` property of your LinkButton dynamically.

```
protected void Page_Load() {

   if(!Page.IsPostBack)
       SetCount();
}

private void SetCount()
{
    int count = caravans.GetNoOfCaravansGreater2000();
    lnkPrice3.Text = string.Format("Greater than 2000({0})", count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void BindCount()
{
    int count = caravans.GetNoOfCaravansGreater2000();
    lnkPrice3.Text = string.Format("Greater than 2000({0})", count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 public int count;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindCount();
    }
    public void BindCount()
    {
        count = caravans.GetNoOfCaravansGreater2000();

    }
```